# Definite integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x (\arctan x)' dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, infinity

I need to calculate definite integral $$I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x (\arctan x)' dx$$

I try it as usual but I have indeterminacy $\ln |x^2| _{+\infty} - \ln |x^2| _{-\infty} = \infty - \infty$. How to accurately calculate it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice:

$$f(x) = x(\arctan x)'=x \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

This is an **odd** function (i.e. $f(x) = -f(-x)$), and thus the integration result is $0$.

**EDIT per comment**

The integration does not exist unless we consider Cauchy principle value:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) \,dx =: \lim_{R \rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-R}^Rf(x)\,dx $$

And in our case, the Cauchy PV is $0$.

Comment: If we integrate over $[-a,a]$ then take limits we get $0$, but should we be able to integrate in any fashion?

Comment: I don't believe the integral of an odd function over $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$ - it's generally undefined.  It does have Cauchy PV of $0$ though.

Comment: @Mark Right, I thought for Cauchy PV, otherwise this thing might not converge..

Comment: The integral fails to exist as an improper Riemann integral and fails to exist as a Lebesgue integral.  It exists, and is equal to $0$, when interpreting it as a Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: When there is $ ∞ $ in the limits, do we mean tending to infinity or just infinity?

Comment: @InternetGuy It is a just a notation, and it depends on how you define your integration is approaching it. For Cauchy PV, we approach both end with the same value (+/-)